# Count objects with ListView

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I try return count register for Sale in template.
I use ListView. And i need return count registers of Sale.

I try

```
#models.py
class Sale(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.date_sale)

...
    @property
    def get_counter(self):
        return Sale.objects.count()

#views.py
class SaleList(ListView):
    template_name = 'sale_list.html'
    model = Sale
    context_object = 'sale_list'
    paginate_by = 10

#sale_list.html
{{ sale.get_counter }}
```

but not work.

How to return count register of Sale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
class SaleList(ListView):
    template_name = 'sale_list.html'
    model = Sale
    context_object = 'sale_list'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SaleList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.get_queryset().count()
        return context
```

If template

```
{{ count }}
```

Comment: Glad to help. :) About you solution- problem, then you call method of object's, but ListView send to template list of objects. If you receive object_list in template, need write {{ object_list.0.get_counter }}  (need use one object)

Comment: I noticed that this solution adds an extra database query to retrieve the total count (via Django Debug Toolbar). Is there any way to avoid that extra hit to the database?

Comment: Here's a solution to my own question above: {{ page_obj.paginator.count }}

Comment: but when we add following code  ``` context['count'] = self.get_queryset().count() ``` it will call queryset again.  have we any alternate solution of that.?

Answer (score 11):

A better solution to this problem is to use:

```
{{ page_obj.paginator.count }}
```

This avoids hitting the database one more time just to get the count, which was already available in `page_obj`.

Comment: Thank you! You are saved half of my working day. I think this reply should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a `get_counter` function or even overwrite the get_context function.

The ListView will call the template with an `object_list` (or in your case, `sales_list`) which is a queryset, so all you need is to access the `count()` function directly from the template.

So, just use the following on your template:

```
{{ sales_list.count }}
```

Comment: I use pagination, and sales_list.count return only this render itens. For all register i used get_context_data. But thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this.

for current object list number show. you can use

```
{{object_list.count}}
```

and for total object list number show. you can use

```
{{page_obj.paginator.count}}
```

here is the preview
[image]